# How to create PSK key?

Tags: tls, openssl

I'd like to create a PSK key to use with TLS-RSA-PSK-WITH-AES-256-CBC-SHA - what is the format of this key?

Comment: This question does not appear to be about cryptography within the scope defined in the [help center](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/help)… it is *“[software recommendation request](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)”*.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the programming aspects of using a cryptographic library, and best answered by reading the documentation anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the Interactive Ruby (irb) command.

```
  bash> irb
  irb> require 'securerandom'
=> true
  irb> SecureRandom.base64(256/8)
=> "qOo64focYhXyCPH3z5zpKyhNqQmTgtAVIP4mgJFnjrM="
```

This will produce a cryptographically secure random bit sequence, encoded in base64. This one is 32 bytes or 256 bits long. If you prefer hex format, try this:

```
  irb> SecureRandom.hex(256/8)
=> "a66d258de75987d31a4537ecd1ff7a34517bf92f2c07abb20fa0fb517f2491f1"
```